# Limit characters returned in h:outputText?

Tags: jsp

Is there anyway to limit the number of characters returned in an h:OUTPUTTEXT ?

For example in jsp file:

```
    <h:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{allTgrpsProperties.trunkGroup}" maxlength="20"/>
    </h:column>
```

But Eclipse give me an error : Attribute maxlength invalid for tag outputText according to TLD.

Actually, if the value's length is 50 character but i want to display it only 10 character. In addition to, this value is a string.

Is there any solution?

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use something like this:

```
<h:column>
    <h:outputText value="#{allTgrpsProperties.trunkGroup.subSequence(0,20)}" />
</h:column>
```

Alternative solution: You can change the getter of `trunkGroup` like this:

```
public String getTrunkGroup() {
    if(trunkGroup.length() > 10)
        return trunkGroup.substring(0, 10);
    else
        return trunkGroup;
}
```

And the you can use it front end like this:

```
<h:column>
    <h:outputText value="#{allTgrpsProperties.trunkGroup}" />
</h:column>
```

Comment: It does not work : The function subSequence must be used with a prefix when a default namespace is not specified.

Comment: what is the type of `trunkGroup` variable?

Comment: maybe you have syntax error or something like that. it must be work.

Comment: take a look at my alternative solution at updated answer